# javascript or jquery window popup with external page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can anyone provide me with some guidence of how to open an external page in a nice looking pop-up window ?

I have lots of dynamic content on a page, and in the following code I'd like to open a pop-up window with the link. For some reason I am absolutely stuck on this one.

```
    function showCourse(code)
{

    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        type: "POST",
        url: 'formPostsUser.php?reqtype=getCourseDetails',
        data:'coursecode='+ code,
        success: function(data) 
        {
             $('body').add('div#lightbox')
             .append(data)
             .animate({width: "350px", height:"250px"}, 1500);

        }
    });
}
```

This function needs editing to open a pop-up window. For some reason, at the moment, if the user presses a link that calls this function it shifts my page to the left of the screen, and show my content ontop of the page and not in a pop-up window.

Any hints will be greatly appreciated
Kind regards
Alex

Comment: yeah. push that data into a window.open result, bro

Comment: I think he wants a popup that is still part of the current page.

Comment: @Justin not sure if u know . . . . but there is a difference between a nice looking pop-up and a new browser page or tab . . that is not accaptable her !!! and bad usability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look into HighSlideJS](http://highslide.com/) it can embed images, iframes, dom content, video, etc. into a popup box.

Comment: How does it not work? You are appending DOM elements to a div and trying to have them pop up. That is what highslidejs does.

Comment: it keeps saying loading. Same with a different jquery plugin. They work on a normal link, but my link is beign created dynamically through JS, and for some reason the pop-ups wont work i find. Same here, I am using lightbox, it doesnt open the pop-up, it just writes over the current content

Comment: Create it with PHP. JS won't run in those types of popups.

Comment: When I just explained why it didnt work earlier I just came back in. Went out for while to come back with a fresh mind. Works like a charm now, thx buddy. Had a bad day before ;)